# For how many values of b mod 55 does the congruence x^2 + x + b = 0 (mod 55) have exactly 2 solutions.

Tags: convergence-divergence

Question: For how many values of b mod 55 does the congruence x^2 + x + b = 0 (mod 55) have exactly 2 solutions?
I tried to use quadratic function to solve but really don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given any prime modulus, this equation has exactly $0$, $1$, or $2$ solutions, respectively, based on whether its discriminant, which is $1-4b$, is a quadratic nonresidue (giving $0$), equal to $0$ (giving $1$), or a quadratic residue (giving $2$). The number of solutions it has $\bmod pq$ is simply the product of the number of solutions it has $\bmod p$ and the number of solutions it has $\bmod q$. Can you use this to figure out how many solutions it must have $\bmod p$ and $\bmod q$ and then count from there?

Comment: No.  Put $b=0,1-4b=1^2$.  Then the equation has the solution set $\{0,10,44,54\}\bmod 55$.  You are missing the fact that $55$ is composite.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, you are correct. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I know for mod 5, if b congruent to 0 or 1 then there is no solution. So for mod 5, does it mean there is 3 values of b to make the congruence have 2 solutions?

Comment: I can also do the same thing for mod 7 but how can I combine these two consequence together?

Comment: I actually did not use quadratic formula to solve it. Since in mod 5, x can only congruent to 01234, so I try one by one and find value of b

Comment: @ZhenqingXu 
1) I think you might have messed up your calculations somewhere - $\bmod 5$, you should get that the solution pairs $(x,b)$ are $$(0,0),(1,3),(2,4),(3,3),(4,0),$$ so it has two solutions iff $b\in\{0,3\}\bmod 5$ (and has only one solution if $b\equiv 4\bmod 5$). 

2) Try using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

3) Since the number $55$ is pretty small, it's feasible to just try all the cases. For larger moduli, this becomes too computationally intensive. I recommend you try to solve it in a method that will apply to the general case.